# Dynamically add new component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been playing with ReactJS and have two components like:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var MyDiv = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
      return (
         <div>
             Hello World
         </div>
      )
   }
});

var MyClickableDiv = React.createClass({
   addDiv: function () {
      alert("Hello World"); //For testing
   }
   render: function () {
      return (
         <div>
             <MyDiv />
             <a href='#' onClick={this.addDiv}>Add new MyDiv</a>
         </div>
      )
   }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is: upon clicking "Add new MyDiv", I want to add a new MyDiv component under the first MyDiv that I already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a more react-minded approach would be to make the state of whether the second div is present or not explicit and put all the rendering inside the render function instead of splitting it, half in render and the other half in addDiv.

```
var MyClickableDiv = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function(){
       return {showDiv: false};
   },

   addDiv: function () {
       this.setState({showDiv: true});
   },

   render: function () {
      return (
         <div>
             <MyDiv />
             {this.state.showDiv ? <MyDiv /> : null}
             <a href='#' onClick={this.addDiv}>Add new MyDiv</a>
         </div>
      )
   }
});
```

If you want addDiv to keep adding divs when you click it again, change the state so that instead of a boolean flag you keep a list of the extra divs that should be rendered.

Comment: Would the list of extra divs then need to iterate over these to display them? I was going to set the state to: `showDiv: []`, and then use a for loop? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Yes that is the idea. You can find a concrete example in the [React tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) when they create a CommentList component.